# How can I make view cshtml for my Edit ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

This is my ViewModel

```
namespace CRUD2.ViewModel
{
    public class CostVM
    {
        public int id { get; set;}

        public string nama { get; set; }
        public string alamat { get; set; }

        public string jenis { get; set; }

        public informasi informasi { get; set; }
        public iseng iseng { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<CRUD2.ViewModel.CostVM>
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="2px;">
        <tr>
            <th>Nama</th>
            <th>Alamat</th>
            <th>Jenis</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.informasi.nama</td>
                <td>@item.informasi.alamat</td>
                <td>@item.iseng.jenis</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.informasi.id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my Controler (Edit and Index)

```
namespace CRUD2.Controllers
{
       public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
       {
        var costumerlist = from cust in db.informasis
                           join ord in db.isengs
                           on cust.id equals ord.id
                           where cust.id == id
                           select new { cust.nama, cust.alamat, cust.jk, cust.kelas, ord.jenis };

        return View(costumerlist.FirstOrDefault());
       }
    }
}
```

How can I make my Edit.cshtml? I dont understand how to make that, I have no idea, and if I have any mistakes in my code, please fix it.. Thanks

Sorry for my Bad English..

Comment: Please have a look at: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor It looks like you are creating an anonymous type, but the view expects a list of CostVM. Furthermore by convention your view name must match the name of the method. So your method is called "edit", than your view must be called "edit.cshtml" as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a custom hybrid of two data sources, which is fine.  You can add an Edit view with:

```
@model dynamic
```

Since you have an anonymous type, but better would be to create a class with all of the properties returned from this select:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
   public string nama { get; set; }
   .
   .
}
```

And then change the query to use this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    var costumerlist = from cust in db.informasis
                       join ord in db.isengs
                       on cust.id equals ord.id
                       where cust.id == id
                       select new SomeViewModel { cust.nama, cust.alamat, cust.jk, cust.kelas, ord.jenis };

    return View(costumerlist.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

And then create a new view for edit which will use this model:

```
@model SomeViewModel
```

To create an edit view would be the same way you created the Index view; right click on the controller action, select Add View and select the model.